# Does using text properties cause memory leaks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, immutability

If a string is immutable, and the Text property of a text box is a string type, will that not result in a massive memory leak if my application makes a lot of changes to the text box?

What is the best practice when working with text properties that are frequently updated?

Comment: What language/platform are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're talking about Java or .NET.)

> will that not result in a massive memory leak if my application makes allot of changes to the text box

No. It may require many strings to be created, but they can then be garbage collected when they're no longer relevant... so there's no *leak*.

You need to be *somewhat* careful about how much garbage you generate, but in the case of a UI the garbage collector is likely to be significantly faster than the UI anyway - I'd expect that you'd get to the point where the UI is failing to keep up with the changes before GC churn becomes an issue.

Comment: Thank you for that answer.
Best practice for using text that changes much, is using a string builder instead of string class. How come a text property is cleaned by the garbage collector, when a string class just keep taking up more memory each time it is edited

Comment: @RuneRafn: No, best practice is to use a `StringBuilder` *to build strings* from many pieces. That's what it's there for. It's not clear what you mean by "a string class just keep taking up more memory each time it is edited" - a new string object is created, and if nothing refers to the old one, it is eligible for garbage collection.